# Accidentally deleted placeholder.jpg and bibliography does not load

Tags: natbib, warnings, overleaf

I accidentally deleted the file "placeholder.jpg" in my Overleaf project directory. Now, I get "natbib warnings" and my references don't show up. Is there a way to recover the placeholder file?

I should add that I'm using the Elsevier template.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) You can recover the placeholder.jpg file from your project's history by downloading a version prior to when you deleted the file, then uploading the missing file to the current version of the project. But that wouldn't have caused any natbib warnings on its own, if you can't resolve those please contact us at support@overleaf.com with your project's URL and we'll take a closer look.

Comment: Thanks @PaulGessler. Yes, you're right. I don't know what changed. I reverted back to an older version but then it kept the warnings. I've emailed you guys with my issue.